# How to optimize Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection that has two subcollections and I'm fetching it like this

```
for (let doc of data.docs) {
  const finalPurchase = {
    ...(doc.data() as Purchase),
    classification: [],
    history: [],
  };
  finalPurchase.classification = await getClassificationDocs(cnpj, doc.id);
  finalPurchase.manufacturers = await getManufacturersDocs(cnpj, doc.id);
  finalDocs.push(finalPurchase);
}
```

And the subcollection query is this

```
const getManufacturersDocs = async (
  cnpj: string,
  parentDocId: string
): Promise<Manufacturer[]> => {
  const manufacturersRef = collection(
    db,
    "company",
    cnpj,
    "purchases",
    parentDocId,
    "manufacturers"
  );

  const manufacturersDocs = await getDocs(manufacturersRef);

  return manufacturersDocs.docs.map((item) => {
    return { ...(item.data() as Manufacturer) };
  });
};
```

Although it works, it's taking a long time to get everything. Is there any way to optimize this?